# GEOS for django on Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: django, ubuntu-11.10, geodjango, geos

Been trying to run a Django MySQL Nginx Stack to run for GIS Support but unable to succesfully compile GEOS dependancy.

I get a make error 1

It would be great if I could get some concrete steps on the same.

Comment: For starters, would be great if you can provide a dump for the error. Would be of great use to understand just which unsatisfied requirement(s) are throwing an error.

Comment: At the End of the ./config command the last three lines say this
Swig: false
Python: false
Ruby: false

make[3]: *** [CoordinateSequenceFactory.lo] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/src/geos-3.2.2/source/geom'
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/src/geos-3.2.2/source/geom'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/src/geos-3.2.2/source'
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1